# SlideMenu with Transparent Actionbar

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

with below code , i make a Transparent Actionbar for my FragmentActivity & all fragments:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#64000000")));

    setContentView(R.layout.main_slidemenu);
             .
             .
             .
}
```

But i have a problem with this , i need to SlideMenu just open under actionbar , but it open i all of layout.

Comment: plz post your slidingmenu setup codes

Comment: Dear @Arash , i use this dample for slidemenu : http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: Use a `SlidingDrawer` if you want to open menu "over" the screen. Actionbar height is 48dp usually, so give the drawer a top margin that much.

Comment: @S.D. , i using NavigationDrawer

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the ActionBar overlay mode.

Enable it for a single Activity by calling `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);` before `setContentView()`. Or in a theme by setting `android:windowActionBarOverlay` to true.

Answer (score 0):

if you've used SlidingMenu library you could use :

```
setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);
```

but according to the link you've provided you have used `NavigationDrawer` , with `NavigationDrawer` i think you could use layout_marginTop for your NavigationDrawer in it's layout xml and for better achievement , get your ActionBar height dynamically then set margin to that.

and also try removing line below:

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

i've used `NavigationDrawer` before without setting Layout_marginTop and Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY and its below my ActionBar.

Comment: right - it was in my Mind that retrieve Actionbar-height then set slidemenu margintop to `Actionbar-height` - but i'm trying for a better way for this problem! - but about `Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` , why i try to removing this?

Comment: @saeid : i'm not sure about Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY , but this makes Activity fullscreen even with ActionBar , so NavigationDrawer wrap your entire Activity and ActionBar will be over NavigationDrawer.

Comment: yes , this happened , ActionBar cover top of NavigationDrawer and i haven't any good idea for this problem! :(